# Epson V500 no longer working after 16.04 upgrade

Tags: 16.04, scanner, epson

This issue is covered in several other posts, but I remain stuck (and not a little frustrated - Epson have lost my business forever). I shall bypass the actions I have taken that failed (to keep this short) and I undid and verified the undo to all the failed actions.

1. Find USB device Id for the scanner: `04B8 0130`
2. Run> `sane-find-scanner`, contains line:

   ```
   could not open USB device 0x04b8/0x0130 at 002:007: Access denied (insufficient permissions)
   ```
3. Installed `xsltproc_1.1.26-8ubuntu1_amd64.deb` (downloaded from here)
4. Installed `iscan-data_1.36.0-1_all.deb` and `iscan_2.30.2-2_amd64.deb` (from the Epson driver download)
5. Reran Step 2 with same result
6. Turned scanner off/on, then ran Step (2), now get:

   ```
   found USB scanner (vendor=0x04b8 [EPSON], product=0x0130 [EPSON Scanner]) at libusb:002:008
   ```

Fantastic - some progress (after hours of faffing)

BUT, `scanimage -L` still fails, as does `xsane` (and simplescan seems to think that the drivers are still missing). I suspect that someone at Epson has a sense of humour (labelling the device PERFECTION). Am about to launch the scanner out of my 2nd floor window. Can any kind soul save me from throwing myself out after it?

```
OS Ubuntu 16.04

Device Epson Perfection V500 PHOTO
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you did not install `iscan-plugin-gt-x770_2.1.2-1_amd64.deb`. This scanner needs a plugin.

If you go to http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/search/01/search/searchModule, search for V500, you will find the whole bundle with iscan and the plugin to install.

If you install the plugin deb, the scanner will start working.

The direct link for the bundle is

http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/du/02/DriverDownloadInfo.do?LG2=EN&CN2=&DSCMI=47266&DSCCHK=0093667d7f2f01295a0f7473e43f69142fca8f87

Comment: You are absolutely correct. Thank-you so much. Along the way, I believed a comment that indicated that this was for SCSI devices. You might have literally saved my life. You have certainly saved the scanner from an abrupt and untimely end.

Comment: Pilot6 - you may want to add the direct link to your answer: http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/du/02/DriverDownloadInfo.do?LG2=EN&CN2=&DSCMI=47266&DSCCHK=0093667d7f2f01295a0f7473e43f69142fca8f87

Comment: @AndroidDev This is a good idea.